# How to target outside $(this) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use `$('.selector').on('change', function(){})` then inside of it, I added `each`. What I want is to target the current `.selector`, if the current item is already selected then make it empty so you can select other item; there are multiple `<select class='selector'>` elements in the DOM. Please see my code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('.selector').on('change', function(){
    var currentSelect = $(this).val();
    
    if(currentSelect == ''){
      $('.selector').each(function(){
        if(currentSelect == $(this).val()){
          alert("Sorry, you cannot select that item again.");
          $(this).val('');
        }  
      });
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="selector">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="Watermelon">Watermelon</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<select class="selector">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="Watermelon">Watermelon</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<select class="selector">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="Watermelon">Watermelon</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<select class="selector">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="Watermelon">Watermelon</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your code is running fine, but you aren't checking if the select is empty first. Once you do that, then compare if user selection = current selection.

Comment: Hi @NathanielFlick . I added that check, please see the code update.

Comment: I think a pretty good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928605/several-select-box-duplicate-values-compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 loops at each change events here.

1. to get all selected values.
2. to hide all values already selected from the other `<select>` elements.

Simple as that.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var selected = []; // Global scope array.
  
  $('.selector').on('change', function(){
    var currentSelect = $(this).val();
    var selected = [];  // Array reset
    
    $('.selector').each(function(){
      var val = $(this).val();
      if(val!=""){
        selected.push($(this).val()); // Array fill
      }
    });
    
    console.log(selected);
    
    $('.selector option').each(function(){
      if($.inArray($(this).val(),selected)!=-1){ // If not in array: hide
        $(this).hide();
      }else{
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="selector">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="Watermelon">Watermelon</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<select class="selector">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="Watermelon">Watermelon</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<select class="selector">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="Watermelon">Watermelon</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<select class="selector">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="Watermelon">Watermelon</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, this would be the answer. By using `$(this)`, you are applying whatever change to all `select` elements on the page. You want to do it just for the one that was clicked. For that reason, you should be very careful with `$(this)` and use `$(event.target)` instead. Read more about the differences here:
[Difference between $(this) and event.target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077859/difference-between-this-and-event-target)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.selector').on('change', function(e){
    var currentSelect = $(e.target).val(); // if you need to pass/submit the value somewhere later
    $(e.target).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
```

Why not simply disable the target element? You can still see what was selected and the user cannot click it again.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a reason to loop through `.each` here.

What you can do, is `.on('change')` create an array of all values of elements with the `.selector` class.  Then once you have that array, check how many instances there are of the element that was just selected.  If that number > 1, then that selection has already been made in a different `.selector` element.

Working Pen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WLvzMM

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.selector').on('change', function(){

    // Put the value of all elements with the class of `.selector` into an array
    var all = $.map($('.selector'), function (el) { return el.value; });

    // Get value of the change that was just made
    var currentSelect = $(this).val();

    // Get the number of occurences of the value that was just selected
    var occurences = $.grep(all, function (elem) {
      return elem === currentSelect;
    }).length;

    // If there is more than one occurence (the one that was just selected), then prevent the selection.
    if(occurences > 1){
      alert("Sorry, you cannot select that item again.");
      $(this).val('');
    }  
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a little bit messy, but it works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".selector").on("change", function(){
    var currentSelect = $(this).val();
    $(this).siblings().on("change", function(event){
      if(currentSelect == $(this).val()){
        $(this).val('')
        alert("Sorry, you cannot select that item again.");
      }  
    });
  });
});
```